# Excel - AND formula not workig as excepted (Need to get value returned by formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula :

```
=IF(AND(G767<>0;I767=0);TRUE;FALSE)
```

`G767` and `I767` Contains number. **Why does this formula return** 0 and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Sound Like `AND` Does not work as excepted

**EDIT**

`G767` and `I767` are given thanks to Formula, I need and `AND` don't take the formula's value but only the formula so how can I select the values returned by the formula and not the formula ?

Example :

`G767` and `I767` are given with this forumla :

```
=IF(G767<>0;'Primary Pricer'!$J$57*Pricing_Calculation!F761;IF(G767=0;'Primary Pricer'!$J$57*Pricing_Calculation!F761+'Primary Pricer'!$J$57))
```

Comment: Have you got 'Transition formula evaluation' checked in the Lotus compatibility options at the bottom of the Advanced section in Excel options?

Comment: Which cell are you entering this code into? Might be an issue with Circular references.

Comment: Indeed the value are given thanks to an other formula.. @StevenPomponio

Comment: @Rory yes, I edited my Issue Hope it does helps...

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comma rather than a semi-colon? `G767<>0,I767=0`

Comment: @StevenPomponio Edited my issue, hope it does help

Comment: @whatapalaver nop, just edited my post please have a look, do not hesitate to upvote if you have no idea it will help..

Comment: Not sure what version of excel you are using but for me, the following works =AND(G767<>0,I767=0) no need for the IF statement. Works even if the cells referred to are formulas. So I can't recreate your problem.

Comment: If you have that option selected, that is why you see 0 and not False. **Un**check it.

Comment: @Rory even if it should return True it return also 0 and not 1 ^^ I think The correct answer was about circular references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if there are any circular references found within the document.

Under `Formulas` -> `Error Checking` -> `Circular References`

[image]

If possible, try and remove the circular reference, however if you can't you can change the settings to let it run.

Under `File` -> `Options` -> `Formulas` -> `Enable iterative calculation`
[image]

Comment: Thank you ! You made my day

Answer (score -1):

change it to string by adding quotes ""

```
=IF(AND(G767<>0;I767=0);"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

Comment: Does not work, something return 0 but I don"t know why

Comment: still 0 or 1 coming?